# Is the sum of the residues always 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The residue theorem requires $f$ be analytic in some $D$ that is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, except for $N$ amount of points (isolated singularities).

It then states: $$\oint_\gamma f(z)\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathrm{Res}(f,z_i)$$

However, if $f$ is analytic, which implies that it's holomorphic, doesn't that also imply that it's path independent (Morera's theorem) and therefore: $$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathrm{Res}(f,z_i)=0$$

In fact, in my notes, it's stated that for $f(z)=\frac{2z+1}{z^4-1}$, which has 4 residues, the sum of them is indeed $0$. I suspect this is not true in general, because $\mathrm{Res}(f,\infty)+\sum_{i=1}^N\mathrm{Res}(f,z_i)=0$ and it wouldn't make much sense to bother defining $\mathrm{Res}(f,\infty)$ if it's going to be $0$ anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the residue theorem requires that $f$ be analytic in a domain (and a neighbourhood of its boundary) except for finitely many singularities. But the hypotheses of Morera's theorem are stronger: $f$ must be analytic in the entire domain (and a neighbourhood of its boundary)—no singularities allowed.

Comment: Oh, okay, I guess that clears it up.